# Regarding PAM via ldap

Tags: authentication, pam, ldap, nss

I have a question for the authentication between Linux and Windows.

When I get an authentication from the OS system such as Linux, then I can use PAM by configuration of "/pam.d".

However, it's the authentication in local only, and I have to make an authentication from Windows not Linux.

So, I'm looking into /etc/shadows and /etc/nsswitch.conf. There is an article for the tip, but it's not enough for me to configure the file by my self..
( URL : https://serverfault.com/questions/538383/understand-pam-and-nss/538503#538503 )

Other articles are saying using OpenLDAP, but it's for Linux not Windows.. I guess..

Is there any way to get the authentication from Window servers via LDAP??

For example of 'nsswitch.conf', if I configure the file like following..

```
passwd:      files dns sss
shadow:      files dns sss
```

Then, it will find the files first and then look into DNS. Then, how can I configure the DNS or /shadow, etc. for the authentication from the remote.

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: Have you read this?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.12.linux.aspx

Comment: Hi, yes I read it but I'm using CentOS7 and Windows Azure. Does it work with the linked information in the condition?
And.. it's using 'windbind', but I need to use 'LDAP'.

Comment: I'm afraid my head is not up in the cloud.  No idea what's possible up there.  Windbind, that's a good one ;-)

Comment: I would like to use the easy way, but.. not possible..T.T..
BTW, Thank you.

Comment: I just had a look for Windows Azure authentication, and the first DuckDuckGo hit was "Windows Azure Active Directory".  So, the old document could still be of value.  At my job, it's how Linux authentication is done.  Once it's set up, you just have to make sure the clocks stay in sync, but you'd want that anyhow.

Comment: I agree with the statement, the old document could still be of value. However, I need to find out the way to authenticate a user via LDAP. Now I'm looking into OpenLDAP.. Perhaps I could get an answer from it in fortune. By changing a URL or DNS something from OpenLDAP server to Azure server..

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to install [sssd](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/) and adjust its config file `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.

There are several options for integrating with MS AD:

- [Integrating with a Windows server using the AD provider](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/ad_provider.html)
- [Integrating with a Windows server using the LDAP provider](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/ldap_with_ad.html)

The latter might be easier in the beginning, but the former can also provide single-sign via *Kerberos*.

Note that *sssd* serves NSS maps *passwd*, *group* and sudoers. Adding `dns` is only useful host the *hosts* map.

So these parts of /etc/nsswitch.conf should look similar to this:

`passwd: files sss
group: files sss
hosts: files dns`